# how to insert single row data into muliple tables

Tags: java, mysql, csv, spring-batch

In our firm, we have a use case to parse a csv file having 50k records. My task is read the csv file line by line, convert into an objets and then insert into a multiple tables. I was using sprint jdbc batch mechanism to write the into a table. Now my problem is i am unable to write data into multiple tables.

```
insert into role(name, code) values(?,?);
insert into person(first_name, last_name, description, role_id) values(?,?,?,?);
```

can somebody tell me how i can get last inserted role_id and then pass it to second query. All is operation is happening inside the jdbcbatcupdate method.

Comment: Could use a stored proc but that has its own issues but i think fine for 50k lines or seperate statements no batch

Comment: Fastest way in mysql is to use LOAD DATA INFILE into a temp table .50k -100k records will be loaded in a temp table very fast.
Then write a stored Procedure with start transaction and end transaction  to read from the temp table and populate main
table 1,2,3 ....n based on data set.

Answer (score 1):

Using JDBC batch update mechanism, there is actually no way to get the generated keys with a driver-independent solution. There is a issue on [Spring JIRA for this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1836) but it is closed as "Won't fix".

Your best bet would be to drop the batching mechanism and update the database line by line. The logic would become : insert new role, get last inserted role_id and use it to insert the new person.

You can retrieve the last role_id using a `GeneratedKeyHolder` like this :

```
KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {           
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        //set values in ps
    }
}, holder);
Long newRoleId = holder.getKey().longValue();
```

Comment: i have done approach in past. It impact performance. because csv may contain 50k records. will it is gud approach to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a subselect for the id in the second value.  Instead of using

```
insert into role(name, code) values(?,?);
insert into person(first_name, last_name, description, role_id) values(?,?,?,?);
```

Why not use (assuming roles are unique):

```
insert into role(name, code) values(?,?);
insert into person(first_name, last_name, description, role_id) values(?,?,?,select id from role where name = ? and code = ?);
```